# What is the best way to integrate Nodejs and Vuejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs3, vite

I want to know the best practices involved in integrating nodejs and vuejs applications.

I looking at various options and I’m not sure which is the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
└───your-folder
    ├───api                  // Your Nodejs server
    └───client               // Your Vue app
```

Create a folder like this. Now start your Node API on any port (for example 3000) and then start your Vue app on different port (for example 4000).

Now you can send any request (GET, POST, PUT etc.) from your Vue app to your Node API. In our case API origin is `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thanks, so I will just build the node for production with this strategy after development?

Comment: You can also put your productions files in nodejs /public directory and don't forget use app.use(express.static("./public"))

Comment: Not separation of concerns and 2 apps in the same place. May not scale well, especially if using some CI.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to have a nodejs API in one place and a VueJS app in another and to communicate between both via API calls.

Not sure which other ones there are.